# Get the ViewModel through a UserControl

Tags: windows-phone-8, user-controls, mvvmcross

I am currently developing a Windows Phone application with the MvvmCross framework.
Whence my question : How do I get an instance of the ViewModel of my UserControl?
Because, `UserControl` does not provide any `ViewModel` field.

Answer (score 1):

Ok sorry for the useless post.

There is a simple way to do that and I don't understand why I didn't think about that sooner.

Anyway, I manage to get my ViewModel through the code behind of my UserControl with the following code :

```
ListProjectsViewModel vm = DataContext as ListProjectsViewModel;

if(vm != null)
{
    // To Do
}
```